# MySQLdb configuration with PyDev

Tags: pydev, mysql-python

How to setup MySqlDb with PyDev (eclipse plug-in). I tried finding but no success.
Can anyone provide any tutorial kind of links for the same.
Using Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

My suggested approach would be

- Create [virtualenv](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/installing.html#creating-virtual-environments) where you install all packages for your project
- Install MySQLdb in this virtual environment (or even better, use [PyMySQL drop in replacement](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyMySQL) which has better installation instructions and no native dependencies making it easier to install)
- In Eclipse project settings, point it to use Python interpreter and PYTHONPATH from virtualenv